# ajax form ignoring my checkbox reseting to default when submit data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My website has a HTML form that needs to be submited through JQuery AJAX:

my problem is that the checkbuttons values are ignored when data is submitted.

HTML code:

```
<form id="form" name="form">
        <fieldset id="fieldset">
            <legend id="legend">Filter</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterFailed" id="filterFailed" a>Failed
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterAlert" id="filterAlert" >Alert
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterWarning" id="filterWarning" >Warning
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterNotReceived" id="filterNotReceived" >Not Received
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterOther" id="filterOther" >Other
            <input type="checkbox" name="filterSuccess" id="filterSuccess" >Success
            <input type="submit"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            e.preventDefault();
                getNotifications();
        });
    });

    document.form["filterFailed"].checked = true,
    document.form["filterAlert"].checked,
    document.form["filterWarning"].checked,
    document.form["filterNotReceived"].checked,
    document.form["filterOther"].checked,
    document.form["filterSuccess"].checked


    getNotifications();

    function getNotifications() {
        var formData = {
            'getAllNotifications': 1,
            'filterFailed'       : document.form["filterFailed"].checked,
            'filterAlert'        : document.form["filterAlert"].checked,
            'filterWarning'      : document.form["filterWarning"].checked,
            'filterNotReceived'  : document.form["filterNotReceived"].checked,
            'filterOther'        : document.form["filterOther"].checked,
            'filterSuccess'      : document.form["filterSuccess"].checked
        };

        $.ajax({
            url     : 'server_script.php',
            type    : 'post',
            data    : formData,
            success :function(response) {
                    alert(response);

            },
        });
    }
```

Question:

Why are the checkboxes reset to their defaults when the form is submitted (my PHP script always receives the default checkbox status "filterFailed = true" ignoring my selections)?

Comment: try checking whether the checkbox has attribute by the name checked instead of .checked like document.form["filterFailed"].hasAttribute("checked");

Comment: @Rudresh it did not work. thanks for your quick response

Comment: replace  e.preventDefault() with  event.preventDefault(); http://jsfiddle.net/u4mS5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by Mohit Arora:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
            getNotifications();
    });
});
```